# I want to free up space from Recovery Mode

Tags: terminal, file-management, storage, macos-sierra

My MacBook's internal storage has reached nearly full capacity (until now I had not received a warning), and I'm unable to boot up the computer because of this. To free up space, I opened Recovery Mode and used the Terminal to delete large, uneeded files. After locating the file, the command I used specifically was `rm -rf <folder>`. Despite this, Disk Utility continues to display my internal storage at nearly full, and the .Trashes folder in my internal storage volume is empty.

Do I need to wait 30 days for the trash to naturally empty? Is there any way to speed up this process? Have I done something wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm currently using a MacBook Pro running MacOS 10.12.6. This machine is probably reaching the end of its life, but there are some files I want to upload before I get rid of it.

Comment: Why did you edit out the image? There is now no information on which to base any answer.

Comment: Answer deleted. Waiting for further details.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled macOS and booted normally, with no loss of files.